# Calculus Disk/Washer method: How did we arrive to this answer?

Tags: calculus

Let R be the region bounded by the following curves.
Use the disk or washer method to find the volume of the solid generated when R is revolved about he y-axis.

y=x, y=3x, y=12

**Answer: $$\int_0^16 15/16 π$y^2$**

This is setting up the integral only. 0, 16 were given in the graph. I followed the formula but I'm lost. Anyone can help so I can compare to my work and see what I've missed?

Comment: Nobody can check your attempt if you don't post it. Anyway, good to know that you have solved it, but I don't think there is any point in keeping your question around.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
pi(y^2-(y/4)^2)dy and solved it from there.